# Saving values to django model through a for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to use a dictionary to store values in a model through a modelform and a view. Today I solve it like this:

```
form.variable_1 = dictionary['variable_1']
form.variable_2 = dictionary['variable_2']
form.variable_3 = dictionary['variable_3']
form.variable_4 = dictionary['variable_4']
form.variable_5 = dictionary['variable_5']
form.variable_6 = dictionary['variable_6']
```

The keys in the dictionary are identical to the field names for the values I want to store. I would like to make the function a bit more pythonic - something like this:

```
for field in form: 
    form.field = dictionary['field']
```

However, I'm not sure how to use the Django ORM to achieve this. The fields I want to iterate are numbered 3-28 in the list of fields, so I guess I would have to slice the fields somehow and create a list based on that?

edit:

models.py

```
class MyModel(Model):
user = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
Instance_name = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
Instance_text = TextField(default='')
variable_1 = IntegerField(null=True)
```

There's a total of 30 variables like variable 1 following it.

forms.py:

```
class MyModelMF(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = [
        'Instance_name',
        'Instance_text'
    ]

    widgets = {
        'Instance_text': Textarea(attrs={"style": "height:4em;" "width:25em;"})
    }
```

views.py (up until iteration starts, excluded return render etc for simplicity)

```
def create_instance(request):
form = MyModelMF()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyModelMF(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid()
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.user = request.user
        form.variable_1 = scores_dict['variable_1']
```

Comment: Can you share your model, form and view? Why are you assigning the values manually from a dict and not populating the form from request.POST if using a ModelForm?

Comment: I have edited the question to add code samples. The values are added through a dictionary which is generated from a function based on user inputs on the template, so the values are different every time they are saved, and they are not input manually.

Comment: Can you share the function that generates `scores_dict`? Do all the keys in the dict map exactly to a field on the model?

Comment: I could, but I don't think it would add anything relevant. Every key from the dictionary is mapped to a field in the model, so writing form.variable_2 = scores_dict['variable_2'] etc works fine now, but it's not as pythonic or scalable as I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to set an attribute of your instance by name. Iterate over the keys and values in your dict and use the keys as the attribute names when calling `setattr`

```
if form.is_valid()
    form = form.save(commit=False)
    form.user = request.user
    for field_name, value in scores_dict.items():
        setattr(form, field_name, value)
    form.save()
```

Comment: Good answer. Worth noting that if the user can control `scores_dict`, they can overwrite parts of the `form` object. For example, if they can make `scores_dict` contain a key called 'user', then they can overwrite the `user` field of the form, which is probably not intended. Without knowing how `scores_dict` is generated, we can't say whether this code introduces a vulnerability.

Comment: This works like a charm and saves a lot of space - beatiful!